# How to run Open MPI program on a databricks cluster with multiple nodes?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, mpi, databricks, openmpi

I am trying to run OpenMPI from a python notebook on databricks clusters (ubuntu).

The cluster has 3 nodes:

```
 Driver node: 8 cores
 two worker nodes: each has 8 cores
```

I found that the Open MPI has been installed on databricks.

My command:

```
sudo mpirun --allow-run-as-root -np 25 --hostfile MY_HOSTFILE ./MY_C_APP
```

I got:

```
ssh: connect to host DRIVER_NODE_IP port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host  ONE_WORKER_NODE_IP  port 22: No route to host
```

In MY_HOSTFILE, all nodes' IP addresses are listed.

I run the command from python notebook on databricks.

```
%sh
sudo ssh -T DRIVER_NODE_IP
```

I got:

```
  ssh: connect to host DRIVER_NODE_IP port 22: No route to host
```

the notebook is run on the driver node through webservice.

I have tried to set ssh key so that each node can be accessed. But, the shell command of "ssh-keygen" cannot be run from databricks python notebook.

Could anybody let me know how I can work out this infrastructure problem?

thanks

Comment: It says `no root to host`, so the node where the notebook runs is not configured to access the cluster network. Not being able to ssh into the driver itself is also weird. Perhaps there is some kind of a NAT in action. Check the network configuration with a tool like `ifconfig`. Perhaps there are internal IP addresses that you can access. Also, why are you running everything as root? MPI and ssh work perfectly fine without sudo privileges.

Comment: @HristoIliev, if I do not run it as root, I will get error. I have tried to set ssh key so that each node can be accessed. But, the shell command of "ssh-keygen" cannot be run from databricks python notebook. thanks

Comment: I see. I have sadly never used Databricks hosted services, so no idea what they are doing there.